# Icon for ipywidgets Button not working in Google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create a button with an icon using `ipywidgets` in Google colab without success.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

my_button = widgets.Button(icon="home")
display(my_button)
```

However, no icon is displayed...

Comment: Some features of Ipywidgets have not been supported on Google Colab. There is an open issue here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/60

Comment: Thanks @HoaNguyen – convert to an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Thank you @YaakovBressler! It is not that much. I think you can suggest integrating more features of Ipywidgets in that issue. I also often Google Colab and it would be great if Ipywidgets' features are totally integrated.

Answer (score 4):

The following workaround was shared with me from [an open issue on github for google colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1302):

```py
# Create the button
my_button = widgets.Button(icon="home")

# Display the HTML for the button
display(HTML('''<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> '''))
# Display the actual button
display(my_button)
```

Two items are overlaid – the font-awesome icon and the actual button – though rendering of the actual button isn't achieved.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer!